# Typed an answer and posted a comment - without the necessary rep.?

Tags: support, reputation, comments, answers

I entered an answer to a question and it got posted as a comment. But I don't have enough reputation to post comments and it was meant to be an answer.

How could this happen? Have I done something wrong? Why was I able to post a comment without the necessary rep.?

Comment: I would suspect this was change from an answer to a comment by a mode. Link to question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible (and likely) that your answer was deemed not sufficent enough to be an answer and migrated to a comment.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite possible that the system converted your answer to a comment - see [**here**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/answer-appears-automatically-converted-as-a-comment) for more details.